# How can I edit Settings.apk in android GB

Tags: android, android-rom

Hi I need to add Tab Named **Developed By** inside option **About Phone** in my `Setting.apk` in Android GB containing Developer name, ROM Developer and Contact with me... etc please help me.

I tried a lot but all attempts failed.

About Phone > Developed By:

[image: About Phone>>Developed By]

After click on "Developed By" take you to this pic:

[image: after click on "Developed By" take you to this pic]

Comment: update your question with code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the [source](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings) for the Settings app. The source is conveniently hosted at github. Change all you want. The relevant links for "About Phone":

1. [xml source](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/marshmallow-release/res/xml/device_info_settings.xml)
2. [java implementation code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/marshmallow-release/src/com/android/settings/DeviceInfoSettings.java)